# loadrdf-tool aborts or stall loading 1B+ triples

Tags: graphdb

I have setup graphdb on a Windows server with 32gb memory. I have modified the loadrdf cmd and added "-Xms16G -Xmx24G".

No I'm trying to import the entire Wikidata rdf-dump but are having difficulties. First I tried with an entity-index-size value of 10.000.000 which worked alright undtil the loadrdf-tool aborted after reaching a little more than 1 billion triples. Then I tried to set an entity-index-size value of 2.000.000.000 but this works worse. Currently it has processed 500.000.000 triples but the load speed has dropped to 7.000 st/s.

Are there any other settings/configurations I should be aware of, that could make the import work?

Answer (score 1):

The public Wikidata RDF dump has about 2 billion statements and probably around 500M unique RDF resources. By default, the entity pool structure (the index of all unique RDF resources) is stored in the off heap memory space, and you will need to reserve at least 8GB. Add at least 3GB more for the OS system, and this means you will need actually to decrease the amount of used memory to "-Xmx20G".

To speed up the data loading speed the GraphDB documentation recommends to use SSD. This will boost the data loading speed since SSD has a much lower seek time.